# create zoom meeting via post man get date in past

Tags: postman, zoom-sdk

hi im trying to create zoom meeting via api
so i follow this link
https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/meetings/meetingcreate
and this is my postman code

```
https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/my-zoom-email/meetings?start_time=2020-11-21T11:00:00Z&duration=50&topic=dddd
```

i get success with this response

```
{
    "page_size": 30,
    "total_records": 1,
    "next_page_token": "",
    "meetings": [
        {
            "uuid": "jLUnAVqtRlWnITbvwOHjPw==",
            "id": 93089037096,
            "host_id": "Uwnvj78cQtKruuouXaV3qw",
            "topic": "aa",
            "type": 2,
            "start_time": "2020-11-16T11:00:00Z",
            "duration": 60,
            "timezone": "Asia/Amman",
            "created_at": "2020-11-16T10:29:27Z",
            "join_url": "the meeting url"
        }
    ]
}
```

now my problem thats the `"created_at": "2020-11-16T10:29:27Z",` not the currect datetime the currect datetime is `2020-11-21 07:16:00`
and the  `"topic": "aa",` is dd not aa
so how can i set the meeting starttime ..
thanks

Comment: you have to do post

Comment: Why are you adding all that to the query param? Are you sure you're using the correct endpoint here. That looks like the response from the Get All Meetings endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Let me clear you first.
When you make a meeting create request, the `created_at` response show date-time in `UTC` format of current date-time.
And look at this `"start_time": "2020-11-16T11:00:00Z"` once again. It's already set as you mentioned in your API request parameter which is

```
start_time=2020-11-21T11:00:00Z&duration=50&topic=dddd
```

If you want to set it properly as your current date-time, it's better to use another extra `timezone` parameter. From response I can see, your timezone is `Asia/Amman`.
So you can make your URL like this:

```
https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/my-zoom-email/meetings?start_time=2020-11-21T11:00:00Z&duration=50&topic=Testing&timezone=Asia/Amman
```

Hope topic name will not change. And it's better to add another parameter name `type` which defines what type of meeting you want to create (There are 4 types). As reference you can check out Zoom's API documentation from https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/meetings/meetingcreate